# easy_install 'develop' command fails to work in virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, easy-install

### Update:

It turns out that the virtualenv was not properly initialized before running `easy_install`. Once this has been rectified, things started to work as intended. There's no solution to post, since the stated problem did not exist in the first place. The *'when I activate the virtualenv'* step was not properly taken (don't ask), so the following malfunction was an illusion.

Case closed.

#### Original question:

I have a virtualenv. Inside it, `sys.path` looks like this:

```
[...,
 '/<inside_virtualenv>/lib/python2.6/site-packages/foo-1.2.egg',
 ...
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/foo-2.0.egg'
]
```

If I `import foo` from inside the virtualenv, I get foo-1.2 imported, as expected.

I have an egg; its setup file lists another egg as a dependency that has `foo=1.2` in its dependencies.

When I activate the virtualenv and try to run `python <my_egg>/setup.py develop`, I get an error:

```
Processing dependencies for <my egg>
Installed distribution foo 2.0 conflicts with requirement foo==1.2
```

I even patched `setuptools/command/easy_install.py` to print `sys.path` right inside the `try` statement that raises this exception. The path is all right, listing `foo-1.2` first and `foo-2.0` distant second.

What am I doing wrong? Is there any way to make easy_install ignore the non-virtualenv `foo-2.0` installation and accept `foo-1.2` inside the virtualenv?

Removing the offending entry from `sys.path` inside my egg's `setup.py` does not help. While `sys.path` only contains the correct version of `foo`, the process fails with the same error.

Comment: Add your solution as an answer - I've made this mistake more than once and it'd be nice to have another solution to hit via da googlez.

Comment: @AlG: there's no proper 'solution' except for running the `activate` script properly for the virtualenv. After this, everythong worked as expected, without conflicts. This all was just a mis-configuration issue.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31809/putting-solved-in-the-title-of-a-question

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: I wish I could post an actual solution. Instead, the whole problem was a result of a stupid mistake. I'll re-formulate the post to better reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

There's another possible case where this can happen, beyond the one you were experiencing directly, but which is easily avoided:

When setting up a new virtualenv, use `--no-site-packages` to avoid including libraries from your system Python installation unless you're certain they don't (and will never) conflict.

Comment: Hmm. As far as I understand, packages installed in a virtualenv always trump system-wide packages when the virtualenv is activated. Using `--no-site-packages` is a surefire way to avoid conflicts with system packages, though.

Comment: @9000 That's the theory. Not so much always in practice, though -- if you're installing something for which a system package provides a dependency (but in an older version unlikely to work) but the requirements.txt doesn't specify a minimum version adequately... well, let's just say I've seen this situation in practice.

Comment: the bit about _other_ eggs possibly not specifying adequate minimum dependency versions is a good warning, thanks.